# Checking the validity of a function's arguments in R

Tags: r

I'd like to create a function that first checks to make sure the arguments passed to that function are valid. My particular function takes two arguments and I've been successful in checking the validity of the first argument. However, checking the second argument is giving me trouble.

I'd like to check that the input for `state` is a member of `state.abb`. This seems to work correctly.

I'd also like to check that the input for `outcome` is a member of `"heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia"`. This doesn't work correctly.

Here's my code so far:

```
best <- function(state, outcome){

  ## Read outcome data

  outcome <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")

  ## Check that state and outcome are valid

  if (!any(state == state.abb)){
    stop("invalid state")
  }
  if (!any(outcome == c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia"))){
    stop("invalid outcome")
  }

  ## The function will do other things after this is sorted out.

}
```

When I enter a *wrong* state abbreviation the function gives me the proper error:

```
> best("FF", "heart failure")
Error in best("FF", "heart failure") : invalid state
```

Now when I enter a *correct* state abbreviation and a *wrong* outcome the function appears to give me the correct error:

```
> best("CA", "this is wrong")
Error in best("CA", "this is wrong") : invalid outcome
```

Yet this same error persists even when I have a valid argument for outcome:

```
> best("CA", "heart failure")
Error in best("CA", "heart failure") : invalid outcome
```

Can anyone give me a bump in the right direction on sorting out the validity check of the second argument?

**Edit**: Per [lukeA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327739/lukea)'s comment it appears the issue might stem from the `read.csv` command. I've now included that command in the above code.

Comment: Not reproducible. `best("CA", "heart failure")` doesn't throw an error here, if `CA` is in `state.abb`. Tip: You could also write `stopifnot(outcome %in% c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia"))`.

Comment: @lukeA You're completely correct. I removed my `read.csv` command from the original post since I didn't think it was relevant, but it appears it's contributing to the issue. Does this help pinpoint anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove" ? If you don't read in your data, how can you process it?  Did you create your sample data somehow else, and if so, please do `str` on both versions. Most likely there's a `class` mismatch somewhere, or possibly a whitespace character getting in the way.

Comment: As per your function, it doesn't matter what you pass as the `outcome` argument, since it is set as the result of reading the `csv` file in the first line of the function. So you are basically overriding the argument value and then receiving the error every time, since it appears that the file you read doesn't contain any of the "legal" values.

Comment: Why is there an argument `outcome` when you import it afterwards from a `csv` file and overwrite it?

Comment: -1 this is exactly the homework of Program Assignment 3 of Corsera R Programming class: https://www.coursera.org/course/rprog

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is that:
the second argument "outcome" is assigned to the csv file content 
according to " outcome <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")"
so the outcome should never valid :)